# limit number of tags shown in tag.php

Tags: tags

Been hitting a nail with this one as i'm very amateur with php. I have a loop in tag.php but it shows all posts with that tag - how can I limit the number to say, 5?

```php
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2 align="center">  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?>  </a> </h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <h2>Woops...</h2>
    <p>Sorry, no posts we're found.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: `wp_reset_query` should only be used to clean up after `query_posts` calls. Since you should never use `query_posts` it follows that you should never use `wp_reset_query`. Burn it from your code with the fire of a thousand suns

Comment: are you using `query_posts`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the main post query, use the `pre_get_posts` filter:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_tags_to_196_posts' );
function limit_tags_to_196_posts( \WP_Query $query ) {
    // we only want tag archives
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_tag() ) {
        return;
    }
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 196 );
}
```

Notice that we check the query first, we don't want to change all queries everywhere or we'll be changing WP Admin or RSS feeds, etc, we only want tag archives

Comment: Thank you. Placed this code in functions.php, and also did a small change to test it (196 to 3) but I still get all posts within the tag.

Comment: @beluoso re:  my original comment on your  question, are you use `query_posts` but didn't include it in your question? Is your main loop for the main query? This is super important